# ASP.NET Core 3.1 unable to get Odata Query parameter

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

Using `ASP.NET Core 3.1` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.5.6`,

When a `HTTP "DELETE"` request is sent to an action method, I am unable to get the
query parameter, the resulting parameter value remains set to `0`.

Here is my HTTP Request:

> https://localhost:8083/api/EventTypes(Id%3D66L)

And my Action Method:

```
    [Route("api/EventTypes({Id})")]
    [HttpDelete]
    // [AcceptVerbs("DELETE")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(Int64 Id)
    {
        DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
        param.Add("Id", Id);
        await Dapper.DapperORM.ExecuteWithoutReturn("event_type_delete", param);
        return Ok();
    }
```

When I inspect the value of `Id` the value is `0`. I have tried changing the type to `string`, and then the value is set to `"Id=66L"`.

I expect this to work but it does not in my case:

> Delete([FromODataUri]Int64 Id)

What is the best/correct way to get the integer value?

Comment: Did you try: `https://localhost:8083/api/EventTypes(66L)`?

Comment: Hi @RomanMarusyk, I was not able to try that request as I am not in control of the request, unless I intercept the request before it get's sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Route Parameter to use this format `Id={Id}` and using `FromODataUri` I managed to get the desired parameter value.

e.g.

```
    [Route("api/EventTypes(Id={Id})")]
    [AcceptVerbs("DELETE")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete([FromODataUri]Int64 Id)
```